# Why asking about advantages of 'early stopping' has been closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions

This question:

- [What is early stopping?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/16/8)

has been closed as off-topic.

I don't see the reason why it should.

The 'early stopping', in machine learning (**branch of AI**) is used to avoid overfitting when training. Therefore I don't see this question as off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

I was one of the close voters, and let me explain here why I voted to close.

As I, and some other users, have said *multiple times* before, we should avoid questions that are only related to machine learning. Those questions are already on-topic on both Data Science and Cross Validated.

The point of creating this site was filling a gap that was not already covered by Data Science and Cross Validated. Early stopping is on-topic on both sites ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=early+stopping), [2](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=early+stopping)). Remember that if this site looks to much like Data Science and/or Cross Validated it *will most likely **not** get out of private beta*.

Comment: Question being on-topic on the other sites, doesn't make it automatically off-topic here. ['Different sites are different communities with different norms.'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90514/191655). I still believe it's about AI, and closing it only, because it's on-topic somewhere, doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

Data science and the Stats SE already have a huge overlap (>~80%), and I am worried to have a third SE that also significantly overlaps with them, so that why I VTC.

I think the best solution would be along the lines of this proposal: [build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with “crossover questions” between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199989/178179).